# Web Service Reference: Location of generated classes?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I created a web service reference in VS 2008.  Should I be seeing some sort of generated .cs somewhere?

Also I created a custom class and am trying to create an instance of this Proxy class but it doesn't know what that object is yet when I try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click show all files in your project and you will see under your service reference "reference.cs"

Comment: why would it be hidden in the first place?

Comment: Because it is generated by a tool and not meant to be edited.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a web service in Visual Studio it will create a file with the extension type *.asmx. If you open this file it will so you where the *.cs file resides. In a Website Visual studio will automatically put it in the AppCode folder.

eg.

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/suburbWebservice.cs" Class="suburbWebservice" %>
```

Hope this helps.